# Servicemix simple bundle missing requirement

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Hello I am new to servicemix and cannot start a simple self-programmed bundle.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<!-- Generated by Apache ServiceMix Archetype -->

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.rupp</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>test</name>

<properties>
   <camel.version>3.0.0-M3</camel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Private-Package>de.rupp</Private-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My camel-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.10.3.xsd">
<camelContext id="Merda" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <packageScan>
         <package>de.rupp</package>
     </packageScan>
 </camelContext>
 </beans>
```

I only have one simple class

```
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:in")
        .id("file-in")
        .log("Nachricht: ${body}")
        .to("file:out");

}

}
```

The resulting MANIFEST.MF is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1560848195732
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Built-By: bla
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: test
Bundle-SymbolicName: test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: de.rupp;uses:="org.apache.camel.builder,org.apache.camel
 .model";version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
Import-Package: org.apache.camel.builder;version="[3.0,4)",org.apache.ca
 mel.model;version="[3.0,4)"
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

when I copy the jar to the deploy folder and use bundle:list
I see it installed
225 | Installed |  80 | 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT                     | test

However I cannot start it.

karaf@root>start 225

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 225: Unable to resolve test [225](R 225.14): missi
ng requirement [test [225](R 225.14)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.packag
e=org.apache.camel.builder)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requi
rements: [[test [225](R 225.14)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org
.apache.camel.builder)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Does anyone know a good tutorial for writing camel bundles?

Thanks,

Hans

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Camel version that ServiceMix is using (ships with out of the box). ServiceMix does NOT support Camel 3.

Also I wonder suggest to look at just using Apache Karaf or alternative runtimes for Camel (Spring Boot, Quarkus, Tomcat, Standalone Camel via Camel Main) as ServiceMix is not so active anymore.

Comment: Changing to <camel.version>2.16.5</camel.version> made it startable. Many thanks. Our management thinks servicemix is great, without bothering to explain why ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your property with this:

```
<properties>
   <camel.version>2.16.5</camel.version>
</properties>
```